# MySQL nonaggregated column using COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I recently moved up to MySQL 5.7 and have encountered the problem with using GROUP BY. I'm not exactly sure how to structure this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm basically wanting to achieve two things.
- Get the count of each storeName
- Get all the rows and order them by the DISTINCT storeName without duplicates.

```
SELECT COUNT(storeName)
     , id
     , storeName
     , mallName
     , address
     , city
     , state
     , zip
     , phone
     , description 
  FROM $tbl_name 
 WHERE storeName LIKE '$myquery%' 
 GROUP 
    BY id
     , storeName
```

Comment: can you show some example data and the expected output?

Comment: User proper `GROUP BY`.  Why are these columns not in `GROUP BY`? `id
     , storeName
     , mallName
     , address
     , city
     , state
     , zip
     , phone
     , description`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly and you need both count() and the rows that make up that count, I believe this isn't possible in a single query. What you could do if this is 100% necessary is take the count(*) with the store names and put them in a temp table. Then join on the temp table on store name to bring the counts in for each store name.
This will give you a count in every row corresponding to the store name. Hope this helps

edit: I made it work in one query. Not sure why I didn't think this was possible
Here's an example

```
select t.storename, c.count,t.* 

from table t

left join (select distinct storename, count(*) as count
           from table 
           group by storename
) as c

on t.storename = c.storename

order by t.storename
```

Comment: Yea thats exactly what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah in that case I would just use the temp table approach and left join on that temp table.

Comment: In my experience, and within reason, there are very few things not possible within a single query.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I added an edit with the solution in one query

Comment: @IanRycroft You should always indent your code by using 4 spaces or pressing CTRL-K.  It makes it much easier to read!